# How to set Date/Time in salesforce using javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-button, datetime, custom

I am updating the record in the javascript while clicking on custom button. I have custom date/time field Approved_Date__c. I need to update that fields also using javascript. How can I assign current date/time to Approved_Date__c field?

I tried like

```
set("Approved_Date__c",NOW());
set("Approved_Date__c",Date.NOW());
set("Approved_Date__c",Date.Time());
```

but i am getting:

> A problem with onclick javascript for this button or link was
>   encountered. Now not defined.

I tried like this also

```
jpt.Approved_Date__c=new Date().toLocaleString();
```

it's showing as:

> {faultcode:'soapenvClient', faultstring:''3/21/2016, 3:05:33 PM' is
>   notavalid value for the type xsd:dateTime',}

Comment: use a `apex:inputhidden` and set the value of that inputhidden

Comment: I am not using any vf page. I am updating this in custom button in standard page.

Answer (score 3):

I got solution for this. I tried like this..

```
jpt.Approved_Date__c=new Date().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are in the right direction. The only thing I see missing is the `{! expression }`.

I believe the first approach will work for you.

> set("Approved_Date__c",**{!** NOW() **}**);

Comment: Hi Manjit, that's also not worked for me.